# cocos2d draw something on top of the sprite

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am very new to cocos2d. I have read the basic concept of sprite and action. I was wondering after I created a sprite (from an image file). and I want to draw some numbers on the sprite on the fly, is that something doable? or you can not draw anything on the sprite after creating from an image?

Thanks for your reply in advance.

Comment: `cocos2d-iphone` and `cocos2d-x` are different frameworks.  Please correct your tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display text or numbers over a Sprite, you can add a UIText widget as a child.

```
auto sprite = Sprite::create("image.png");
addChild(sprite);


auto text = Text::create();
text->setString("Test");
// Position the text in the center of the sprite
text->setPosition(Vec2(sprite->getContentSize().width*.5,
                       sprite->getContentSize().height*.5));
sprite->addChild(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

draw sprite using  Render Texture and then you can add as a child of the sprite .

Comment: As the OP wants to draw characters, why not a label of some sort, as a child of the sprite?  If the OP is new to these frameworks, I think he will find that easier than getting involved with rendering.